# How to tell android to parse an XML response of a page iam redirected to?

Tags: java, android, httpclient

I'm trying to parse an XML response within an Android app. The technique of parsing itself is not the problem, but the process of receiving the XML makes it difficult to do it the common way.

More in detail:
I request a xhtml website with the apache httpclient (in Android). The website is located on a Java EE Application Server (AS). I give two GET parameters with the request (username, password).

The website is located in a secure area on the AS, so first of all the AS forwards me to the login page. The loginpage takes the username and password (from the GET parameter) and logs me in automatically. If the login credentials are valid I'll get redirected to the requested XHTML page. This is the site I want to parse with the android SAX parser.

But when I try to do this, the only respose I'm able to parse is the login page, not the page. I'm redirected to after successfull login. Can anyone tell me how to instruct the android apache http client to take the response of the redirected page (for later parsing) after the automatical login process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found my solution with the help of this blog entry:
http://ginger-space.blogspot.com/2007/04/httpclient-for-form-based.html

Just updated the Code to the current Apache Client andere IT worked.

Answer (score 0):

The logged-in user is stored in the HTTP session which is identified by a cookie with the name `JSESSIONID`. You need to ensure that you pass the obtained cookie back on every subsequent request, also on the redirects. Otherwise the server will consider the redirected request as unauthorized and redirect you once again back to the login page.

Managing the obtained cookies can be done with help of the [`CookieStore`](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/client/CookieStore.html) which you need to set in the [`HttpContext`](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/protocol/HttpContext.html) which you in turn need to pass on every [`HttpClient#execute()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/client/HttpClient.html#execute%28org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpUriRequest,%20org.apache.http.protocol.HttpContext%29) call.

```
HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
CookieStore cookieStore = new BasicCookieStore();
HttpContext httpContext = new BasicHttpContext();
httpContext.setAttribute(ClientContext.COOKIE_STORE, cookieStore);
// ...

HttpResponse response1 = httpClient.execute(yourMethod1, httpContext);
// ...

HttpResponse response2 = httpClient.execute(yourMethod2, httpContext);
// ...
```

Comment: I did exactly what you said, but every further request leads me back to the login page. the response is always the layout of the login.jsp.
I debugged the project and saw that there is a cookie stored with a sessionID but it seams the authentification method is not working. What did you mean by "passing cookies on the redirects"? Iam getting redirected by the Server, so how to pass a cookie in this moment?